# subset fasta file using id file

Tags: perl, file, subset, fasta

I have been stuck with some script!

Well i made this script in 2008 and now i am using with some modifications and i get error!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

sub getSequences ($) {

    my $file = $_[0];
    open (INFILE, "<$file") || die "Error1 in opening in file: $file. $!\n";

        my @lines = <INFILE>;
        my $header; my %header2seq = ();

        foreach my $line (@lines) {
            chomp $line;
            if ($line =~ /^(>.+)$/o) { 
                $header = $1; 
            }
            else {$header2seq {$header} .= $line; }
        }
#print %header2seq;
    close (INFILE);
    return (\%header2seq);
}

sub MakeSpList ($) {

    my $sp_list = $_[0]; my %sp_names = ();
    open (INFILE2, "<$sp_list") || die "Error2 in opening in file: $sp_list. $!\n";
    my @sps = <INFILE2>;
    foreach my $line (@sps) { chomp $line; $sp_names {$line} = 1; }
    close (INFILE2);
#print Dumper (%sp_names);
    return (\%sp_names);
}



 sub CompareSpList2Sequences ($$$) {
     my $ref_header2seq = $_[0] ; my $ref_sp_names = $_[1]; my $file = $_[2];
     open (OUTFILE, ">$file.subdata") || die ("Error3 in opening out file: $file.subdata. $!\n");
     foreach my $key (keys %$ref_header2seq) {
         $key =~ m/^>([A-Z]+[0-9]+[A-Z+]).+$/o;
        #print "$1\n";
         my $header_sub = $1;
         #print $header_sub, "\n";
         #print $ref_sp_names, "\n";
         if (exists $ref_sp_names -> {$header_sub}) {
             my $seq = $ref_header2seq -> {$key};
             print OUTFILE ">$key\n$seq\n";
         }
     }  
     close (OUTFILE);
     return "42";
}


my $fasta_seqs = $ARGV[0]; my $sp_list = $ARGV[1];


my $ref_header2seq = getSequences ($fasta_seqs);
my $ref_sp_names = MakeSpList ($sp_list);
CompareSpList2Sequences ($ref_header2seq , $ref_sp_names, $fasta_seqs);

exit;
```

What i want to do is:

i have a fasta file with sequences:

YAL004W YAL004W SGDID:S000002136, Chr I from 140760-141407, Genome Release 64-2-1, Dubious ORF, "Dubious open reading frame; unlikely to encode a functional protein, based on available experimental and comparative sequence data; completely overlaps verified gene SSA1/YAL005C" ATGGGTGTCACCAGCGGTGGCCTTAACTTCAAAGATACCGTCTTCAATGGACAACAAAGAGACATCGAAAGTACCACCACCCAAGTCGAAAATCAAGACGTGTTCTTCCTTACCCTTCTTGTCCAAACCGTAAGCAATGGCAGCGGCGGTAGGTTCGTTAATAATACGCAAGACATTCAAACCAGCAATGGTACCAGCATCCTTGGTAGCTTGTCTTTGAGAATCGTTGAA

YAL005C SSA1 SGDID:S000000004, Chr I from 141431-139503, Genome Release 64-2-1, reverse complement, Verified ORF, "ATPase involved in protein folding and NLS-directed nuclear transport; member of HSP70 family; forms chaperone complex with Ydj1p; localized to nucleus, cytoplasm, and cell wall; 98% identical with paralog Ssa2p, but subtle differences between the two proteins provide functional specificity with respect to propagation of yeast [URE3] prions and vacuolar-mediated degradations of gluconeogenesis enzymes; general targeting factor of Hsp104p to prion fibrils" ATGTCAAAAGCTGTCGGTATTGATTTAGGTACAACATACTCGTGTGTTGCTCACTTTGCTAATGATCGTGTGGACATTATTGCCAACGATCAAGGTAACAGAACCACTCCATCTTTTGTCGCTTTCACTGACACTGAAAGATTGATTGGTGATGCTGCTAAGAATCAAGCTGCTATGAATCCTTCGAATACCGTTTTCGACGCTAAGCGTTTGATCGGTAGAAACTTCAAC

and i have another file with ID's:

YAL005C
YAL012W

I want to retrieve the sequences and the all header when match with ID's file.

**but i get this error: don´t print anything!**

Please can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

- i already searched for other methods (and i can´t get the results either) but i really want to know about this error!
- no bioperl please!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so - line 45 is:

```
     if (exists $ref_sp_names -> {$header_sub}) {
```

Your error is telling you that `$header_sub` is undefined. It's *set* by:

```
my $header_sub = $1;
```

Which follows:

```
     $key =~ m/^(>[A-Z])\s.+$/o;
```

So - this means the regex isn't matching. I don't see any `>` in your sample data, so it can't match it. When the match fails, `$1` is undefined, hence your error. What do you get out of your `print $key` statements?

I would also note - `.+$` is most likely redundant. Likewise - the `o` flag - you probably don't want that either. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using Bioperl? Here's some code to get you started.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my $fasta = shift; #this will just push whatever in cli in.
my $seqio_obj = Bio::SeqIO->(-file => $fasta, -format => 'fasta');

while ( my $seq = $seqio_obj->next_seq){
     print $seq->id . ' = ' . $seq->seq() . "\n";
     #in here you can do your fasta handling with the seq obj
}
```